# Essence of matrix in linear regression model

Tags: regression, self-study

[image]

b) I cannot understand the purpose of A matrix

Also the purpose of X'e matrix in part f)

Comment: A clue: 0.2 = 1/5 =1/n, where n=dimension of y = number of rows of x.

Comment: still cannot crack it , please take a look at f) part also